# Error compiling with Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I'm trying to compile a program in C++ which uses OpenCV 2.4.10

But during compilation time it can't find the Imf symbol, and gives out a list of errors like

/usr/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_exr.o): In function `cv::ExrDecoder::readHeader()':
(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x12): undefined reference to`Imf::globalThreadCount()'

I'm compiling with

g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -static -o "find_box_layout"  ./src/find_box_layout.o   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lm -ljasper -ljpeg -ltiff -lpng -lz -lpthread -lrt

Any help with this?

Comment: Try   \`pkg-config --libs opencv\`  instead of individual opencv libs

Comment: add -lImf to cmdline

Comment: I would suggest using CMake to generate the project files and then doing the compilation. That is the easiest and safest way.